# How to know, After which Partition unallocated space is available ? (Powershell or Command)

Tags: powershell, cmd, disk, diskspace

I am trying to use Command or PowerShell to know where on a disk unallocated space is available.

For example below the unallocated space is present after G: drive (or Partition 1).

Using the command `echo list disk | diskpart` I can only know the Unallocated space.

[image]

Is there any way to know this information?

Comment: You can enumerate [partitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394135(v=vs.85).aspx) via `gwmi Win32_DiskPartition` and detect the gaps by comparing StartingOffset property with an accumulated value of Size properties.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for Windows 8/2012 Server or newer:**

I think you could do this (needs to be run with Administrator rights) to return an object with each volume that can be extended (from which you can then deduce there is free space after the volume):

```
Get-Volume | Where DriveLetter -ne $null | ForEach-Object {
    $Size = Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter $_.DriveLetter
    If ($Size.SizeMax -gt $_.Size) { $_ }
}
```

- `Get-Volume | Where DriveLetter -ne $null` gets all drives that have a letter
- `$Size = Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter $_.DriveLetter` gets the sizemin and sizemax of each drive
- `If ($Size.SizeMax -gt $_.Size) { $_ }` returns the volumes which can be extended (their size max is bigger than the current volume size).

Comment: Powershell version is 2.0.. Looks like the above command runs on 3.0

Comment: @Chand It's not just PowerShell version, the Storage cmdlets weren't added until Server 2012/Win8.

Comment: I found a solution. Using starting and end address.